# What does numpy.max function do?

Tags: python, numpy, max

I went onto a piece of code which goes like this:

```
while numpy.max(abs(A - B)) > 0.01:
```

I am trying to replace the `numpy.max` with some regular Python (math?) function, but I can not find what exactly does `numpy.max` does.

I tried googling but I only found:
[`numpy.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) which is not the same as `numpy.max` I suppose.

And:
[`numpy.amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) which is again not what I need.

Does anyone know how I could replicate this numpy.max funtion into some standard python one?

EDIT: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: According to [this old message](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.devel/6625), "numpy.max exists for historical reasons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replicate the behavior of `np.max` very easily in pure Python, simply because multi-dimensional arrays aren't standard in Python. If the `A` and `B` in your code are such arrays, it would be best to keep the NumPy function.

For flat (one-dimensional) arrays, the Python `max` and `np.max` do the same thing and could be exchanged:

```
>>> a = np.arange(27)
>>> max(a)
26
>>> np.max(a)
26
```

For arrays with more than one dimension, `max` won't work:

```
>>> a = a.reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> max(a)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous [...]
>>> np.max(a)
26
```

By default, `np.max` flattens the 3D array and returns the maximum. (You can also find the maximum along particular axes, and so on.) The Python `max` cannot do this.

To replace `np.max`, you'd need to write nested loops over the axes of the array; effectively trying to find the maximum in a list of  nested lists. This is certainly possible, but is likely to be very slow:

```
>>> max([max(y) for y in x for x in a])
26
```

Answer (score 5):

`numpy.max` is the same thing as `numpy.amax`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.max # Notice it says 'amax' in the output
<function amax at 0x0228B5D0>
>>> numpy.max is numpy.amax
True
>>>
```

Or, more specifically, `max` is an alias for the `amax` function.

The purpose of this function is listed in the [docs link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) you gave, but it seems that it is mainly used to find the maximum value inside a `numpy.array` regardless of how many nested levels it has.  You can mimic this behavior with a simple function to flatten a list:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # Use 'yield from flatten(item)' in Python 3.3 or greater
            for sub_item in flatten(item):
                yield sub_item
        else:
            yield item
```

and the [built-in `max` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(flatten(my_list))
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> def flatten(lst):
...     for item in lst:
...         if isinstance(item, list):
...             for sub_item in flatten(item):
...                 yield sub_item
...         else:
...             yield item
...
>>> array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> max(flatten(array))
6
>>>
```

Comment: Note that `yield from` here relies on Python 3.3 or greater.

Comment: True.  The OP didn't say what version he is on, so I prefer to use the newest.  If anyone is running an older version though, simply replace `yield from` with a normal for-loop: `for i in flatten(item): yield i`.

Comment: It's a fine choice, but most projects built around NumPy are still on 2.7 and will be for a long time. NumPy itself works fine now in Python 3, but so many associated libraries and tools do not that it creates a severe problem for many numpy-centric projects.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But now I am even more confused, because the initial `A` and `B` are in fact floats not arrays:
https://github.com/Sandia-Labs/PVLIB_Python/blob/master/pvlib/pvl_ephemeris.py#L128

Comment: @iCodez - The function appears to be written to work on arrays or scalars.  In that code example, `EccenAnom` can be an array, not just a scalar.  (Note that the inputs to the function are all documented as array-like objects. Anything involving a time or date will be an array, e.g. `T1`.)  On a side note, the reason that `np.min(2.0)` will return a scalar (actually a numpy float, not the python float that was passed in) is that numpy functions are generalized to work with arrays of any shape or size, including 0-length arrays.  It's a pattern across numpy. No reason to break it for `min`.